# Web stacks - listing of common web stacks/environments

Tags: web, development-environment

Just out of curiosity - I know there's LAMP - Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP. But what other abbreviations for web stack alternatives are there? anything like LAMR - Linux, Apache, MySQL Ruby on Rails?

Could someone please provide a listing of various common web stacks/environments?

Answer (score 2):

MEAN

- MongoDB
- express.js
- angular.js
- node.js

The common denominator among these technologies is javascript. Developers using the MEAN stack can reason about the data being stored, searched, and displayed in the same way across the technologies.

This stack also usually has an Nginx server in front of it for security and load balancing.

Answer (score 2):

I hoped to find an overview here, but alas, I'll just chip in an acronym I recently came across as it typified myself; the WISA stack:

- Windows (Operating system)
- IIS (Application server)
- SQL Server (Database)
- ASP.NET (Server side Language)

So hopes that leaves you a bit wisa' to :). Notice the client side is missing here. Personally I mostly stack on AngularJS (with Bootstrap layout) and WEBAPI (2) to handle the AJAX calls. But they don't create particularly nice acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

I think the new term-de-jour is 'Web-Stack' because the you now need a LAMP and several LED's.

Used to be that LAMP was the acronym that put a nice tidy bow on the open-source-community' web-stack options.

i.e: LAMP:

- Linux
- Apache
- MySQL
- Python || Perl || PHP.

  - python == mod_python, and mod_wsgi... which gives you django, turbogears, web2py, etc.
  - perl == mod_perl, which gives you Catalyst, Mason etc.
  - PHP == Zend, Yii

These were considered to be the 'Open-Source-Community' stack, and a tidy acronym L-A-M-P
summed it up nicely. Now I think you have to add 2 alternatives to the dbms slot. SQLite && PostgreSQL, also there is a glaring absence from the application stack language slot, as you pointed out. Ruby-on-Rails.

Finally I feel obligated to point out that this space has grown alot:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks

With the advent of Web 2.0 and additional necessities in the env like XMPP or AMQP.
The term L-A-M-P has been replace with the more generic Web-Stack.

I highly encourage you to investigate the user-community size before embarking into the web-stack journey. Also remember when the term L-A-M-P was coined the 'explosion' of client-side technologies had not become so prevalent.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)

Answer (score 0):

MERN

- MongoDB
- Express.js
- React.js
- Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Vangie Beal has been maintaining a compilation of the growing list of stack acronyms, here: https://www.webopedia.com/reference/webstack-acronyms/

To save you a click, here's the current list:

- AMP  Apache, MySQL, and PHP (with the omission of an operating system)
- BAMP BSD, Apache, MySQL, and PHP
- BAPP BSD, Apache, PostgreSQL, and PHP
- FAMP FreeBSD, Apache, MySQL, and PHP
- FWAP Firebird, Windows, Apache, and PHP
- FWIP FreeBSD, Windows, IIS, and PHP
- JAMP Java, Apache, MySQL, and PHP
- JOLT Java, Oracle, Linux, and Tomcat
- LAMJ Linux, Apache, MySQL, JSP servlets
- LAMP Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP
- LAMAR    Linux, Apache, MySQL, AJAX, and Ruby on Rails
- LAMR Linux, Apache, MySQL, and Ruby
- LAPP Linux, Apache, PostgreSQL, and PHP
- MARS MySQL, Apache, Ruby, and Solaris
- MAMP Macintosh OS, Apache, MySQL, and PHP
- NAMP NetBSD, Apache, MySQL, and PHP
- NAPP NetBSD, Apache, PostgreSQL, and PHP
- OPAL Oracle, PHP, Apache, and Linux
- SAMP Solaris, PHP, Apache, and Linux
- WAMP Windows, Apache, MySQL, and PHP
- WIMSA    Windows, IIS, Microsoft SQL Server, and ASP
- WISA Windows, IIS, Microsoft SQL Server, and ASP
- XAMPP    (X could by any one of the following four operating systems; Linux, Solaris, Macintosh, or Windows), Apache, MySQL, PHP, and Perl

Answer (score -1):

@bart I've always heard of your "wisa" stack as WINS:

- **W**indows
- **I**IS
- .**N**et
- **S**ql

You say the client side is missing here, but its not. .NET MVC with razor and async js is an inherent part of the .NET framework, being both a server side and client side framework... sure you can add a js framework on top, but it's not a necessity.

**Edit:** 
I just found that WINS and WISA are different, with what [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack) has to say:

- **WISA** using A = [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) representing ASP (Active Server Pages) in the .NET framework, as just the backend framwroke, allowing coding in any .NET supported language (C#, VB).
- **WINS** using N = [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) representing the entire .NET framework